# Pig Hadoop MATCHES Default?

Tags: regex, hadoop, match, apache-pig

Every RegExp is slightly different. When it comes to Pig's `match` functionality, does:

```
X = FILTER A BY (f1 matches 'apache');
```

==

```
X = FILTER A BY (f1 matches '^apache$');
```

or

```
X = FILTER A BY (f1 matches '.*apache.*');
```

? In other words, is `.*` automatically implied in a `match` or does it always need to be included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of regular expressions in Pig is that supported by Java as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

In other words, nothing is implied, if you want `.*` you have to specifically add it to the `matches` statement just like you would do in Java in a `Pattern.compile`.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I always forget that Pig is Java-based.

Comment: It's true that Pig is _a strange animal_ sometimes !

Comment: Ha, ha. Well, you know what they say: PIG really is smarter than DOS. . .or is that, pigs are smarter than dogs?